# what are the right or common steps to successfully build a structural equation model?

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have learned theories about structural equation modeling but don't have enough experience building a structural equation model. I have spent too much time struggling with building a good SEM. I have some questions about the steps to build a structural equation model and hope someone would give me the answer and save me. I am using JMP pro 16.

**Q1. Is there any problem with my own steps to build a structural equation model and is there any step I missed?**

My steps:

1. I am using maximum likelihood estimation, so check the distribution of each variable that may be endogenous variable in the model and transform any of them that is not normal distritbuion;
2. rescale some variables with very large or small variance to avoid potential estimation problems;
3. I have more than 50 variables related with several aspects (around 3 - 5) of a natural system (eg. water, habitat, air). I would like to use some of them to build 3 to 5 latent variables which represent different aspects of the natural system. Then I would like to use some observed variables representing human development as exogenous variables in final structural equation model to see how human development affects several aspects of a natural system then affects an animal group. The following diagram is the conceptural model.

[image]

4. run correlation analysis for the 50 variables, based on the result and existing theories, I grouped variables with correlations > 0.3 and theoretically falling into the same aspect (some variables were in several groups). So I got several groups of variables.
5. run factor analysis for each group. In each group, I selected 2-3 variables that have high and similar loadings in the same factor as indicators for a latent variable (this step tends to be subjective);
6. run confirmatory factor analysis with selected variables (see diagram below). If pass (based on fit indices, indicator reliability, composite reliability, construct maximal realiability, construct validity matrix), use these latent variables to build structural equation model with observed variables (human development, animal group). If not pass, change the combination of variables until pass.

[image]

7. build structural equation model and check the fit indices.

**Q2: what are the right or common steps to successfully build a structural equation model?**

I have seen some answers or videos mentioning conducting clustering analysis, PCA, and factor analysis before CFA but I am not sure. Also could anyone recommend me any articles/books/videos giving step-by-step instructions to build a SEM? Thanks.